# Eclipse Java EE Indigo 's XML formatting is suddenly screwed up

Tags: eclipse, formatting

A few days ago it was just fine. I haven't made any change to the IDE or anything else in the preferences.

Looks like random instability, but I hope I'm wrong, I don't want to go through the IDE setup again.......

Here are two screenshots to tell the story:

Before Ctrl+Shift+F (format):
[image]

After (format results):
[image]

What can I do about it?

I've tried comparing settings in another Eclipse setup that I have which has XML formatting working properly. (Window -> Preferences -> XML -> XML Files -> Editor). Also (Structured Text Editors).

Comment: That's not the "XML Editor" editor (its tabs are "Design" and "Source").  Maybe this one has a different formatter and preferences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.

It looks like "Android Common XML Editor" took over, and the above crappy formatting belongs to it.

All I had to do is right click on the XML file and choose **`Open With` -> `XML Editor`**.

Answer (score 1):

You can revert the default editor for XML files to be the original XML Editor at Preferences / General / Editors / File Associations:

[image: Make XML Editor the default editor]